# List names of files containing a string that occurs between two other strings

Tags: text-processing, osx, xml

I need to print a list of files with match a specific pattern -- a string occurring between two other strings. How do I do that. I don't want to extract text, just list the files that match this pattern.

I need a command that will match and list all filenames which contain an instance of the string `PREFETCH` which occurs somewhere between these two strings: `advanced_override.begin` and `advanced_override.end`. The files are all present in the same directory, so the command should search the contents of the current directory '.' and list the filenames which match the specified pattern.

UPDATE:

It must have something like this: `advanced_override.begin <lots of text> PREFTECH <lots of other text> advanced_override.end`. I need it to match this string somewhere between those two strings and there can be lots of other text before or after `PREFETCH`.

UPDATE TWO:

The input files are XML files. And the section beginning with `advanced_override.begin` and `advanced_override.end` can be large with many lines of text.

Comment: You mean filename or the file content?

Comment: Yes. I want to list the filenames.

Comment: Please provide examples of input and desired outputs -- otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: Okay. I added more detail.

Comment: So, the entire string the files must have is `advanced_override.beginPREFETCHadvanced_override.end` ?

Comment: Before you head off in the wrong direction of regexps: [Don't parse XML or HTML with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).  It [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/137158).  if you have to do it in sh, use something like `xmlstarlet`, otherwise both `perl` and `python` have excellent library modules for parsing XML.

Comment: I can give you an answer with some XML sample. There are a lot of options. But DON'T go after regex - it's the wrong tool for this job. It will produce nasty brittle code, and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about parsing a specific XML document without revealing what the document structure looks like. Any answer would be guesswork, even if a proper XML parser was used.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pcregrep` if available, with the `-l` switch, to only list the names of files that match:

```
pcregrep -lM '(?s)advanced_override\.begin.*PREFETCH.*advanced_override\.end' ./*
```

This searches in multiline mode for those two strings with `PREFETCH` in between. It assumes there are only text files in the current directory (if that's not the case you could use a `for` loop or `find`) and also that each file contains a single section that starts with `advanced_override.begin` and ends with `advanced_override.end` - with multiple sections it may be better to use a negative lookahead before `PREFETCH` e.g.:

```
pcregrep -lM '(?s)advanced_override\.begin(?:(?!advanced_override\.end).)*PREFETCH.*advanced_override\.end' ./*
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. I have a Mac and can't seem to find a version of this utility for mac.

Comment: After installing Homebrew (https://brew.sh), `brew install pcre` provides `pcregrep`.

Answer (score 0):

The above warnings, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287992/list-names-of-files-containing-a-string-that-occurs-between-two-other-strings#comment503745_287992) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287992/list-names-of-files-containing-a-string-that-occurs-between-two-other-strings#comment503675_287992), but especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4957508) about trying to parse XML files with regular expressions are well-heeded. In general, XML text may not be confined to a single line, but since in this case you're searching for specific single words, and on the assumption that they are not themselves broken apart to multiple lines, you could use a simple awk script that keeps "state". If it sees the next expected word, it increments the `state` value. If it finds all of the expected patterns in the right order, it sets a `found` variable which we then base a return code off of:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *
do
  awk '
/advanced_override\.begin/ { state=1; }
/PREFETCH/ && state == 1 { state=2; }
/advanced_override\.end/ && state == 2 { found=1; }
END {
  if (found)
    exit 0
  else
    exit 1
}
' "$f" && printf "Found in: %s\n" "$f"
done
```

Given these 3 sample input files:

```
$ cat input1
junk
advanced_override.begin other text
other text
PREFETCH other text
other text
advanced_override.end

$ cat input2
just some stuff
advanced_override.end

$ cat input3
junk
advanced_override.begin other text other text PREFETCH other text other text advanced_override.end
junk
```

A sample run of the script produces:

```
Found in: input1
Found in: input3
```